# JS output has "strings"\n"strings" instead of actually creating a new line - Coursera little lemon receipt maker

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am taking a lab quiz for a Coursera class in JavaScript.

Currently, I am not passing this quiz even though I output in chrome console and node.js meets the requirement. Please help!

```js
// Given variables
const dishData = [
    {
        name: "Italian pasta",
        price: 9.55
    },
    {
        name: "Rice with veggies",
        price: 8.65
    },
    {
        name: "Chicken with potatoes",
        price: 15.55
    },
    {
        name: "Vegetarian Pizza",
        price: 6.45
    },
]
const tax = 1.20;

// Implement getPrices()
function getPrices(taxBoolean) {
    for(let i = 0; i < dishData.length; i++){
        let finalPrice
        if(taxBoolean === true){
            finalPrice = dishData[i]['price'] * tax
        } else if(taxBoolean === false){
            finalPrice = dishData[i]['price']
        } else {
            console.log("You need to pass a boolean to the getPrices call!")
            return
        }
        console.log("Dish: " + dishData[i]['name'] + "Price: $" + finalPrice)
    }
}

// Implement getDiscount()
function getDiscount(taxBoolean, guests) {
    getPrices(taxBoolean)
    if (typeof guests == "number" && guests > 0 && guests < 30){
        let discount = 0
        if(guests < 5){
            discount = 5
        } else {
            discount = 10
        }
        console.log('Discount is: $' + discount)
    } else {
        console.log('The second argument must be a number between 0 and 30')
    }
}
// Call getDiscount()
```

When I submit this, the results are:

[image: Results from quiz console]

But when I run the same code in node, outputs are:

[image: See here the outputs are already in new-line]

Why is there "\n" in my output?? How can I get it to output the expected output?

Comment: maybe it wants a space in between name and price? `dishData[i]['name'] + " Price: $"`

Comment: .....you are correct...how did i miss this

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
console.log("Dish: " + dishData[i]['name'] + "Price: $" + finalPrice)
```

To this:

```
console.log("Dish: " + dishData[i]['name'] + " Price: $" + finalPrice)
```

Now you can submit that code

```
// Given variables
const dishData = [
    {
        name: "Italian pasta",
        price: 9.55
    },
    {
        name: "Rice with veggies",
        price: 8.65
    },
    {
        name: "Chicken with potatoes",
        price: 15.55
    },
    {
        name: "Vegetarian Pizza",
        price: 6.45
    },
]
const tax = 1.20;

// Implement getPrices()
function getPrices(taxBoolean) {
    for(let i = 0; i < dishData.length; i++){
        let finalPrice
        if(taxBoolean === true){
            finalPrice = dishData[i]['price'] * tax
        } else if(taxBoolean === false){
            finalPrice = dishData[i]['price']
        } else {
            console.log("You need to pass a boolean to the getPrices call!")
            return
        }
        console.log("Dish: " + dishData[i]['name'] +" Price: $" + finalPrice)
    }
}

// Implement getDiscount()
function getDiscount(taxBoolean, guests) {
    getPrices(taxBoolean)
    if (typeof guests == "number" && guests > 0 && guests < 30){
        let discount = 0
        if(guests < 5){
            discount = 5
        } else {
            discount = 10
        }
        console.log('Discount is: $' + discount)
    } else {
        console.log('The second argument must be a number between 0 and 30')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

console.log("Dish: " + dishData[i]['name'] + "Price: $" + finalPrice)

**Change the line above to this,
it will work out**

console.log(`"Dish: "${dishData[i]['name']}`, `"Price: $" ${finalPrice}`)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
// Given variables
const dishData = [
  {
    name: 'Italian pasta',
    price: 9.55,
  },
  {
    name: 'Rice with veggies',
    price: 8.65,
  },
  {
    name: 'Chicken with potatoes',
    price: 15.55,
  },
  {
    name: 'Vegetarian Pizza',
    price: 6.45,
  },
];
const tax = 1.2;

// Implement getPrices()
function getPrices(taxBoolean) {
  for (let i = 0; i < dishData.length; i++) {
    let finalPrice;
    if (taxBoolean === true) {
      finalPrice = dishData[i].price * tax;
      console.log(`Dish: ${dishData[i].name} Price: $${finalPrice}`);
    } else if (taxBoolean === false) {
      finalPrice = dishData[i].price;
      console.log(`Dish: ${dishData[i].name} Price: $${finalPrice}`);
    } else {
      console.log('You need to pass a boolean to the getPrices call!');
      return;
    }
  }
}

// Implement getDiscount()
function getDiscount(taxBoolean, guests) {
  getPrices(taxBoolean);
  if (!isNaN(guests) && guests > 0 && guests < 30) {
    let discount = 0;
    if (guests < 5) {
      discount = 5;
    } else if (guests >= 5) {
      discount = 10;
    } else {
      console.log(`${guests} is not a number!`);
    }
    console.log(`Discount is: $${discount}`);
  } else {
    console.log(`The second argument must be a number between 0 and 30`);
  }
}

// Call getDiscount()
getDiscount(true, 6);
```

Comment: Tested code, 100% grade on coursera.